# (change) doesn't work when all checkboxes are selected using a "Select All" checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 4 and I have a bunch of checkboxes that are created in a loop. When I click them individually `(change)` works fine but if I use the select all `checkbox` it doesn't trigger the `change` on the individual checkbox inputs.

let me know. Currently the value of each `input` is set to `sc.id`. I was planning on adding them to an array whenever `(change)` was triggered but its not working when I select all.

What am I doing wrong? If anybody has a better suggestion please let me know

html

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"  (change)="allSelected = !allSelected">

<div *ngFor="let sc of scs?.data">
    <input  type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [value]="sc.id" [checked]="allSelected" ( change)="onSCSelect($event)">
</div>
```

component

```
allSelected = false;

onSCSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

I created plunker to recreate the problem
https://embed.plnkr.co/TFxziXAEeutvLZ5rUXZS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `[(ngModel)]` to achieve desired results.

**HTML**

```
    select all
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [(ngModel)]="allSelected" (ngModelChange)="onAllSelectedChanged($event)">
    <br/>
    <div *ngFor="let sc of scs">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [(ngModel)]="sc.checked" (ngModelChange)="onSelectionChanged($event)">
    </div>
```

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent {
  allSelected = false;
  scs = [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 4}
  ];

  onAllSelectedChanged($event) {
     for(let i=0; i<this.scs.length; i++) {
       this.scs[i].checked = this.allSelected;
     }
  }

  onSelectionChanged(isSelected) {
   if (!isSelected) {
     this.allSelected = false;
   }
  }
}
```

See updated plunker for details:

https://plnkr.co/edit/uSsI5YnBYShyIykAI7Vs?p=preview

Comment: the problem is that `scs` array is coming from my database so there is no 'checked' property

Comment: You can easily extend it on the client. Just iterate over it once you get it and add that property.

Comment: I may have over 1000 records so I dont know if its a good idea to do that. Also another problem is that if I uncheck a value it wont update

Comment: See my update https://plnkr.co/edit/uSsI5YnBYShyIykAI7Vs?p=preview . You can skip this property, it will be automatically set by the framework. Also I've added code that unchecks allSelected

Comment: How can I update if I uncheck a value in the `ngFor` so that when I submit values to the database they will be correct

Comment: what do you need to send to DB?

Comment: I'll explain in more detail. Right now I can only select all/unselect all in your example. I want to make it select/unselect all checkbox BUT I also want to let the user select all but than unselect some checkbox if they want. Each checkbox in the `ngFor` will have a `[value]` of `sc.id` which will be sent to the database if a checkbox is selected.

Comment: It's how it works currently. If you need to collect them and send to server you can either iterate over them and push to some array those that have `.checked === true` or you can control this in `onAllSelectedChange` and `onSelectionChanged` methods.